# UIAlertView Display while iPhone is asleep and locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uialertview

I am writing an app the is pretty much always going to be open (hardly ever would run in background) and I want to be able to alert the user with a sound, vibrating the phone, and showing an alert message when there is a state change.  The problem I am having is that when I use the UIAlertView, the AlertView seems to be hit or miss whether it plays the sound and/or vibrates.  For example, sometimes it only alerts the user after the phone is unlocked.  Is there a way that I can make the UIAlertView more aggressive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 4, Push Notifications are no longer the only option.

You'll want to look into the UILocalNotification class. It provides similar functionality without having to setup/maintain a push notification server.

More information here: [Local Notification Programming Guide.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)